# Trouble polling for OID values within tables

Tags: cisco, snmp, oid, mib

I'm very confused about which OIDs are supported by my device, specifically for the CISCO-    IPSEC-FLOW-MONITOR-MIB.

It seems like some OIDs within that MIB are supported, while other OIDs aren't. The OIDs that aren't supported seem to be specifically table OIDs. However, I have no problem polling for table OIDs in other MIBs. I thought that if a MIB was supported by a device, then all of the OIDs within that MIB were supported...

If it helps, a specific example of an OID I want is  1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.3.1.4 and my image is c7200-ik9s-mz.124-25c.bin.

Thanks! I'm more than willing to post more output, feel free to ask!

UPDATE

SNMPWalk output of the MIB is appended below:

```
compass@adc:~$ snmpwalk --version
NET-SNMP version: 5.4.3
compass@adc:~$ snmpwalk -v2c -cpublic 10.2.12.2 .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.1.1.0 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.1.0 = Gauge32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.2.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.3.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.4.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.5.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.6.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.7.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.8.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.9.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.10.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.11.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.12.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.13.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.14.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.15.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.16.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.17.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.18.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.19.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.20.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.21.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.22.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.23.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.24.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.25.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.1.26.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.1.0 = Gauge32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.2.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.3.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.4.0 = Counter64: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.5.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.6.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.7.0 = Counter64: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.8.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.9.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.10.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.11.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.12.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.13.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.14.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.15.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.16.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.17.0 = Counter64: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.18.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.19.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.20.0 = Counter64: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.21.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.22.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.23.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.24.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.25.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.26.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.27.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.28.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.29.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.1.30.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.4.1.1.1.0 = INTEGER: 200
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.4.1.1.2.0 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.5.1.1.1.0 = INTEGER: 200
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.6.1.0 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.6.2.0 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.6.3.0 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.6.4.0 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.6.5.0 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.6.6.0 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.6.7.0 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.6.8.0 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.6.9.0 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.6.10.0 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.6.11.0 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.6.12.0 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.6.13.0 = INTEGER: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Turns out to have been just a coincidence that tables weren't responding.

As far as I can see, no IPSec policy or tunnel information is available via SNMP until the tunnel is active, aka traffic has been sent through it. This explains why I wasn't getting any response from the OIDs I cared about even though I'd added policies, I simply hadn't activated the tunnels.

Thanks for all your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Is that OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.3.1.4 (means cipSecEndPtLocalAddr1) in your mib? (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/CISCO-IPSEC-FLOW-MONITOR-MIB.txt on my servers)

How does it precisely behave? Could you paste your snmpget with output and snmpget version?

Comment: I added the snmpwalk of the whole MIB. You list a Linux filepath for the MIB, but I'm working on a Cisco device and am not sure how I'd look at the contents of the MIB.

Comment: I never used those table OIDs, but this really looks, that it's not returned by the device. I don't have IPsec enabled Cisco device right now, but this command could give you bit more information: `snmptable -v2c -cpublic 10.2.12.2 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.3.3.1.4`

Comment: But getnext should perform ok on table values i think, so if it was included, then snmpwalk should be ok with it.